# Karate V1.3.0 is changing jsons to maps inside javascript functions

Tags: karate

I am upgrading Karate from V1.1.0 to V1.3.1 and having issues with javascript functions that were working previously. (I also tested with V1.2.0 and V1.3.0, V1.2.0 was working as expected, V1.3.0 had same issue as V1.3.1)

The issue I seem to have is that functions that are being passed json objects from feature files, now seem to be passed maps, then the functions that do object comparisons are now failing.

I have gone through the V1.3.0 release notes and couldn't see anything that would be affecting it like this. The closest I found was a link to a comment on the Graal upgrade that could affect calling js functions within other js functions (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2009#issuecomment-1228632313) but that seemed to be more about how they are called rather than other issues.

In my feature file I have the below code:

```
* json provider = read('classpath:provider.json')

Given path 'v1', 'ads'
* retry until findObjectInArray(response.adUnits, provider) === true
When method get
Then status 200
```

The findObjectInArray function lives in its own file that contains the below code:

```
function findObjectInArray(array, adUnit) {
    return !!array.find(unit => equalObjects(unit, adUnit));
}
```

Then the equalObjects function lives in it's own file with the code below:

```
function equalObjects(obj1, obj2) {
    const objectKeys = Object.keys, typeOfObj1 = typeof obj1, typeOfObj2 = typeof obj2;
    return obj1 && obj2 && typeOfObj1 === 'object' && typeOfObj1 === typeOfObj2 ? (
        objectKeys(obj1).length === objectKeys(obj2).length &&
        objectKeys(obj1).every(key => equalObjects(obj1[key], obj2[key]))
    ) : (obj1 === obj2);
}
```

Before upgrading it was working fine, but afterwards the retry condition was never satisfying, and I could see from the responses that the object did exist in the array.

I added some logs to the two functions and found the below differences:

V1.1.0 and V1.2.0:

findObjectInArray values

```
array = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
adUnit = [object Object]
```

equalObjects values

```
obj1 = [object Object]
obj2 = [object Object]
```

V1.3.0 and V1.3.1:

findObjectInArray values

```
array = [{"adProvider":"P0","adUnitType":"OUTSTREAM","insertionType":"SSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"MIDROLL","params":{"purchasedEntitlement":"{{purchasedEntitlement}}"}},{"adProvider":"P1","adUnitType":"INSTREAM","insertionType":"CSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"PREROLL","params":{}},{"adProvider":"P2","adUnitType":"INSTREAM","insertionType":"SSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"MIDROLL","params":{}},{"adProvider":"P3","adUnitType":"OUTSTREAM","insertionType":"SSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"MIDROLL","params":{"purchasedEntitlement":"{{purchasedEntitlement}}"}},{"adProvider":"P4","adUnitType":"INSTREAM","insertionType":"SSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"MIDROLL","params":{"purchasedEntitlement":"{{purchasedEntitlement}}"}},{"adProvider":"P5","adUnitType":"OUTSTREAM","insertionType":"SSAI","inStreamAdPosition":"MIDROLL","params":{"videoId":"{{video.id}}"}}]
adUnit = {adProvider=FREE_WHEEL, adUnitType=OUTSTREAM, insertionType=SSAI, inStreamAdPosition=MIDROLL, params={videoId={{video.id}}}}
```

equalObjects values

```
obj1 = {adProvider=P0, adUnitType=OUTSTREAM, insertionType=SSAI, inStreamAdPosition=MIDROLL, params={purchasedEntitlement={{purchasedEntitlement}}}}
obj2 = {adProvider=FREE_WHEEL, adUnitType=OUTSTREAM, insertionType=SSAI, inStreamAdPosition=MIDROLL, params={videoId={{video.id}}}}
```

Because the jsons now seem to be maps, the former string values of the Keys are now being seen as

```
function () { [native code] }
```

and not being seen as equal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly related to this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2224 - so please help by providing a simple way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - that said I would personally never do this kind of nested function thing you are doing, and if you mention WHY, I' should be able to suggest a better "karate" way to do it

Comment: It does look like the two are related yes. I will work on submitting the way to replicate today. I am interested to know the 'karate way' you would approach this as well, I went down this route as we can't use 'contains' assert as part of retry evaluations, but would prefer to use karate to do this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try 1.4.0.RC3 which has been released. It should solve the issue.